# Ruby `prepare': ERROR: prepared statement "should_insert" already exists (PG::DuplicatePstatement)

Tags: ruby, prepared-statement, pg

I've looked the link

[How to fix PG::DuplicatePstatement: ERROR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146436/how-to-fix-pgduplicatepstatement-error)

but it still did not solve the error message I'm getting

```
`prepare': ERROR:  prepared statement "should_insert" already exists (PG::DuplicatePstatement)
```

Where do I put the block of code from the answer in the above link?  Do I have to call a method in order for it to execute?

```
db_connection = PGconn.connect("localhost", 5433, '', '', "dev_ddb", "user", "pass")

db_connection.prepare('should_insert', 'SELECT COUNT(*) from users where user_id = $1')
```

Comment: I created a new initializer in the config folder called pg_init.rb and put the code from the "How to fix..." link above.  But, it still gives me the same error.  My code is in a file called app.rb and I'm testing it using ruby app.rb.  Not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working by deallocating the prepared statement.  I inserted this line right after the exec_prepared statement.

```
db_connection.exec("DEALLOCATE should_insert")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try with a begin-rescue block to check if the statement is already prepared or not, something like:

```
begin 
  db_connection.describe_prepared("should_insert")
rescue PG::InvalidSqlStatementName
  db_connection.prepare("should_insert",<<-SQL)
    'SELECT COUNT(*) from users where user_id = $1'
    SQL
end
```

and then exec it with

```
db_connection.exec_prepared
```